# What is the airfoil of the Tecnam P2002?

Tags: airfoil

Does anyone knows what airfoil is used on Tecnam P2002? I need it for my report but I can't seem to find anything from the internet.

Comment: I did a few searches as well and couldn’t find anything.  Maybe try  contacting the company and see if they’ll tell you.

Comment: All of Tecnam's aircraft use a NACA 63A series airfoil, but which specific one in the series I don't know.